# keeping date format after post to another page using google chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome

I have date format with `(dd/mm/Y)` when I post it to another page it change to `(Y-mm-dd)`

how to keep first format after posting ?

**Note:** in Firefox there is no problem the format of date is same, but in Google chrome I have this problem also I changed default language to English UK

Comment: first page :


    <form name="input0" action="frame2.php" method="post">
    <input type="date" name="T2" size="13" >
    <button name="B2" type="submit">



next page :
    echo $_POST['T2'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after getting date, format it as you wish with date function in server side.

I hope it will solve your problem

```
<?php

$T2 = $_POST["T2"];

$T2 = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($T2));

echo $T2;

?>
```